# Android -Fragment returns same layout on orientation change

Tags: android, orientation

I have one Fragment which has two layouts with the same name in different folders (layout and layout-land ) when device orientation is changed fragment display always portrait layout in manifest i have this property for activity 
  android:configChanges="fontScale|screenSize|orientation|locale"

Answer (score 1):

When you use `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in your manifest the activity is not recreated when device orientation changes and the layout continues the same.

If you want that onCreate to be called again on orientation change don't use those options in manifest.

Comment: is it possible  without removing this android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

Comment: No, onCreate must be called again to inflate the other layout